# How to reverse a long sum without losing the first digit after the sum reverse?

Tags: java, math, reverse, long-integer

I've completed a program where it reverse long sum's, but for some reason when I try to reverse the sum of two long values it drops the first number. The first number I use is 1234567890000000000 and the second 1234567890. When I do the calculations the total adds to 1234567891234567890 and suppose to reverse to 0987654321987654321. Instead my program drops the zero and return a result of 987654321987654321. Is my while loop math off? When you try smaller integers like 567 and 456 = 1023 reversed 3201. I think when a zero is at the end of any value it reverse incorrectly.

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class Exercise3
{    
    public static void main(String args[])

    {

       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Enter first number: ");

       long n1 = sc.nextLong();

       System.out.println("Enter second number: ");

       long n2 = sc.nextLong();

       long sum = n1+n2;

       long reverseSum = 0;

       long rem;

       while(sum != 0)
       {
        rem = sum % 10;
        reverseSum = reverseSum * 10 + rem;
        sum = sum / 10;
       }

       System.out.println("The reversed sum is " + reverseSum);

     }
```

}

**EDIT**

after trying the code below, I am getting a compiler error:

```
StringBuilder reverseSum = new StringBuilder(sum);
System.out.println("The reversed sum is " + reverseSum.reverse());
String tempValue = reverseSum.toString();
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - Erroneous sym type:  at
>   Exercise3.main(Exercise3.java:27)
>   /Users/dgrate321/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippe‌​ts/run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 11 seconds)

Comment: If you want to keep the 0's in front, use string.

Comment: use a string.formatter to 0 pad any leading 0's in your resulting reversed number when you output it to system.out

Comment: Integers don't have leading zeros. There's no such integer as `01`, it's `1`. There's no such number as `099`, it's `99`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead my program drops the zero and return a result of
>   987654321987654321. Is my while loop math off?

the issue is not with your code, you simply cannot have integer values with a leading `0`. if you want to keep the leading `0` you'll need to store it as a string.

```
StringBuilder reverseSum = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(sum));
System.out.println("The reversed sum is " + reverseSum.reverse());
```

if you want the `StringBuilder` as a string:

```
String tempValue = reverseSum.toString();
```

**EDIT**

here is the full code to accomplish the task at hand:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
    long n1 = sc.nextLong();
    System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
    long n2 = sc.nextLong();
    long sum = n1+n2;

    StringBuilder reverseSum = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(sum));
    System.out.println("The reversed sum is " + reverseSum.reverse());
}
```